# Conversion of media from 720p to 1080p and vice versa

Tags: image, video, resolution, screen-resolution

Let's say my computer's resolution is 1920*1080 and I am watching a movie on it which is 720p. The aspect ratio is the same, 16:9 but how is scaling of pixels done? Is something like Nearest Neighbours algorithm used?

Comment: Do you have any particular video software in mind?

Comment: That would depend on the media player, nearest neighbors is one option.

Comment: @rhughes, no. I just wanted to know, because even though the source is supposedly HD, that particular scaling algorithm can reduce the quality of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling algorithms might vary. Movie scaling typically takes place in hardware - video adapter receives original movie resolution and scales automatically for presentation purposes.

Some MSDN pointers on scaling modes/algorithms:

- [GDI Scaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [GDI+ Scaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Filtering in Direct3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)